# Android ListView not showing rows in fragment

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask, parse-platform, android-arrayadapter

I have a listview that is supposed to be populated with ParseObjects from an AsyncTask class. From the logcat, the asynctask retrieves the objects from the server successfully. But, these objects do not show up in the listview. I am using a fragment for this. Please help.
This is the fragment class.

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment{

    public HomeFragment(){}
    String theLocationOfCinema;
    List<ParseObject> result;
    View rootView;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    ListView listView;
    GridViewAdapter mCardArrayAdapter;
    private List<Movie> cards = null;


    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle state) {
        super.onActivityCreated(state);
        new RemoteDataTask().execute();
        listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.sampleListView);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        theLocationOfCinema = this.getArguments().getString("location");
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }

    private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Movie>>{

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Create a progressdialog
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            // Set progressdialog title
            //mProgressDialog.setTitle("Parse.com Custom ListView Tutorial");
            // Set progressdialog message
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            // Show progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected List<Movie> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            cards = new ArrayList<Movie>();
            HashMap<String, Object> paramss = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            paramss.put("theLocation", theLocationOfCinema);
            ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("getMovieIdsInCinemass", paramss, new FunctionCallback<ArrayList<ParseObject>>() {
               public void done(ArrayList<ParseObject> ratings, ParseException e) {
                   if (e == null) {
                       result = new ArrayList<ParseObject>();
                       Set<String> titles = new HashSet<String>();
                       for(ParseObject item : ratings) {
                            if(titles.add(item.getObjectId())) {
                                result.add(item);
                            }
                        }
                       for(ParseObject human : result )
                       {
                           Movie map = new Movie();
                            map.setTitle((String) human.get("Title"));
                            cards.add(map);
                           //Log.e("cloud code example", "response: " + human.getObjectId());
                           Log.e("cloud code example", "response: " + human.get("Title"));
                       }

                      //Log.e("cloud code example", "response: " + ratings);
                   }
               }
            });
            return cards;
            //return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Movie> result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
            mCardArrayAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(getActivity(), result);

            // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
            if (listView != null) {
                listView.setAdapter(mCardArrayAdapter);
            }
            // Close the progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();

        }
    }       
}
```

And this is the Adapter Class

```
public class GridViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Movie>{
    private Context context;
    private List<Movie> movieslist;


    public GridViewAdapter(Context context, List<Movie> movieslist) {
        super(context, R.layout.movies_row_item, movieslist);
        this.context = context;
        this.movieslist = movieslist;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView title;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return movieslist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Movie getItem(int position) {
        return movieslist.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public List<Movie> getList(){
        return movieslist;
    }

    public void setItemList(List<Movie> ilist){
        this.movieslist = ilist;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.movies_row_item, parent, false);


        Movie mv = movieslist.get(position);
        TextView tt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        tt.setText(mv.getTitle());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

This is the xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             tools:context=".MainActivity" >

     <ListView
        android:id="@+id/sampleListView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:divider="#CCCCCC"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" >
    </ListView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of dangerous to init `listView` after lauching your task, as you do not know when OnPostExecute will happen. Try this :

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle state) {
    super.onActivityCreated(state);
    listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.sampleListView);
    mCardArrayAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(getActivity());
    listView.setAdapter(mCardArrayAdapter);
    new RemoteDataTask().execute();
}
```

=> Basically, the adapter initialization in the onActivityCreated method.

And in your OnPostExecute method, just put the results in the adapter :

```
protected void onPostExecute(List<Movie> result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter
    mCardArrayAdapter.addAll(result);
    mCardArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    // Close the progressdialog
    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
}
```

Don't forget to add this constructor to `GridViewAdapter`

```
public GridViewAdapter(Context context) {
    super(context, R.layout.movies_row_item);
    this.context = context;
}
```

Comment: Could you add your xml layout file ?